# Set Current Page as Datasource for Maps rendering

Tags: sxa

Our application is on Sitecore 9.0.2 with SXA 1.8

We have a module to list all office locations , each location would have a location detail page

Each location detail page should contain a Map with office location coordinates plotted on the map

To achieve this

1. we have created a partial design with map a few other components
2. Assigned this partial design to a Page design
3. Created a Page and added below templates to the page

[image]

4. Associated the Created Page design to the newly created Page
5. Added Coordinate details to the page 
   [image]
6. But These Co ordinates are not plotted on the page :(

[image]

Am i Missing Anything?

Expected Behavior : when a content author populates the coordinates on the page , the map should plot those coordinates as POI

**Update:**

I have tried adding Current Page to POI , the map is not plotting the co ordinates

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Map rendering from SXA has its own data source and can't point to a page. But you can turn on any page to be Point of Interest by adding `IPoi` base template. This template is located here: `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Geospatial/IPoi`.

After doing this your page will have the following section:

[image]

Like I mentioned in the first sentence - it won't work when you will point page as a data source for the Map. This rendering is expecting a different data source. What is more, it is not how PoIs (Points of Interests) works in SXA. You can display dynamic PoIs or static ones. Dynamic ones come from search - that is not a case here. You can also select some static ones (take a look [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-map-rendering-fields.html)) and I think it is what are you looking for. But the problem is that you can select static PoIs from a different location (from under the Data item).

What you can do here is to switch to RAW values and put ID of your page to the POI field in the Map rendering data source item:

[image]

I was not testing it but it should work and solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @Dawid , thanks for you reply , i have tried to explain the Question better , please let me know if am missing anything

Comment: @ManoharR.A I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @Dawid , Here is what i have done, added IPOI to my page template , added coordinates to it , Coordinates Pin is not plotted on the map ,Each location will have its own Page (Item) so how can i assign Page ID to the POI multilist ?

Comment: @SitecoreNoob Please check the article https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2016/10/build-location-finder-search-using-sxa.html from Michael West. It will help you build the map related page.